# Spring State Machine - Define machineId when using StateMachineModelConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

When defining state machine with `StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer` you can easily define `machineId`:

```
config.withConfiguration().machineId("statusMachine")
```

But when defining with [StateMachineModelConfigurer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54823162/spring-statemachine-configure-from-database) (e.g. for DB driven data)

> ```
> @Bean
> public StateMachineModelFactory<String, String> modelFactory() {
>     return new CustomStateMachineModelFactory();
> }
>
> public static class CustomStateMachineModelFactory implements StateMachineModelFactory<String, String> {
> @Override
> public StateMachineModel<String, String> build() {
>     //..
> } 
> @Override
> public StateMachineModel<String, String> build(String machineId) {
>     return build();
> }
> ```

There isn't option to define `machineId`, I read [State Machine ID](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-statemachine/1.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/sm-machineid.html)

> What all these has to do with a machineId? StateMachineModelFactory also have a method StateMachineModel build(String machineId) which a StateMachineModelFactory implementation may choose to use.

But I don't see how to define `machineId` for specific state machine